# Select in C Socket Programming receives only one connection

Tags: c, sockets, select

I am using Select to monitor events in Files Descriptors.
in a infinite loop I have seen that at each repeatition, `FD_ZERO` is called and then all file descriptors are attached with `FD_SET`. All this each time the loop begins.

```
   while(TRUE)  
   {  
     //clear the socket set 
     FD_ZERO(&readfds);

     //add master socket to set 
     FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);  
     max_sd = master_socket;  

     //add child sockets to set 
     for ( i = 0 ; i < clients ; i++)  
     {  
        //socket descriptor 
        sd = client_socket[i];  
        FD_SET( sd , &readfds);  

        //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select 
        // function 
        if(sd > max_sd)  
            max_sd = sd;  
      }  

    //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , 
    //so wait indefinitely 

    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

    /*
        ...  */ 
     }
```

My question is : can I do the same without using `FD_SET` each time the loop repeats. I mean using `FD_ZERO` and attaching the `MASTER SOCKET` before the loop and if there is a new socket we receive it and use `FD_SET` and `FD_CLR`to remove it when disconnected. I tried but it causes the programm only receives one socket connection, after that it does not longer receive connections

Answer (score 1):

> can I do the same without using FD_SET each time the loop repeats

No. `select()` modifies the FD sets. You have to reset them before each `select()`.

You could save a copy of the entire sets and just reassign, instead of your loop: but if actions in the select loop modify the sets you have to modify the master copy, not the one `select()` is using.

Comment: No, it means that your code is one way and a straight assignment from a master copy is another way. It also *says* exactly that.